# CTkToplevel is brought to the front and then goes back

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am encountering a really weird problem in `customtkinter`.

I created a `CTkToplevel` window and brought it to the front using `lift()` method.
It got to the front, and immediately after was sent behind my root window.

#### Simplified Code Using `customtkinter`:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class Win(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Top window").pack()


def show_win():
    global top_win
    if not top_win or not top_win.winfo_exists():
        top_win = Win(root)
    top_win.lift()
    top_win.focus_force()

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry('500x500')
top_win:Win = None
ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Show Top Window", command=show_win).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

I converted the code to `tkinter` and it worked perfectly.

#### Using Standard `tkinter`

```
import tkinter as tk

class Win(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Top window").pack()

def show_win():
    global top_win
    if not top_win or not top_win.winfo_exists():
        top_win = Win(root)
    top_win.lift()
    top_win.focus_force()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
top_win:Win = None
tk.Button(root, text="Show Top Window", command=show_win).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

The code worked well in `customtkinter` once I disabled the root window:

#### Using `-disabled`

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class Win(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.master.attributes('-disabled', True)
        ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Top window").pack()
    
    def destroy(self):
        self.master.attributes('-disabled', False)
        return super().destroy()

def show_win():
    global top_win
    if not top_win or not top_win.winfo_exists():
        top_win = Win(root)
    top_win.lift()
    top_win.focus_force()

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry('500x500')
top_win:Win = None
ctk.CTkButton(root, text="Show Top Window", command=show_win).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I need the root window enabled.

---

I also tried to use the `topmost` attribute, but it didn't work as well:

#### Using `-topmost`

```
class Win(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.attributes('-topmost', False)
        ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Top window").pack()
```

---

How can I ensure that my `CTkToplevel` window stays on top *without disabling* the root window?

(I want it to still go back when the root window is focused)

Comment: Make the toplevel a transient window of the root window.

Comment: @acw1668 But then the `Toplevel` doesn't go back when focusing on the root window

Comment: Have you asked the author of customtkinter, or looked through the code to see if intentionally raises or lowers windows? I've seen a small handful of odd design decisions in that code, maybe this is one more.

Comment: Then try to delay the calling of `.lift()` and `.focus_force()` a bit using `.after()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you, it worked. Though it is a bit of a workaround.. Isn't there a more direct approach?

Comment: If I have other more direct approach, I would suggest.  As Bryan said, it is a design issue of customtkinter.